# How to flag a deleter's delete or closer's close?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I haven't had a need to, but let's say a user gets hold of lots of reputation points or some other condition which gives them influence.

Let's call him (or her) X. So X is bored and wants to pick on a low reputation points person, Y, and deletes his (or her) post. What can Y do about it? Is there some sort of accepted way to handle this? I doubt it's happened often if at all, but it is best to be prepared.

Comment: It takes 5 people to close (and delete as well, I think), so it would be a cabal of five theoretical morons out to get you.

Comment: @Plutonix In most cases, only 3 delete votes are required; [but sometimes more](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/259867) based on the score.

Comment: You should [**politely**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) ask for it to be undeleted, and not in the unconstructive way you have done here. Unfortunately, there's not much one can do about a hypothetical situation. I suggest you provide more details about why you want your post to be undeleted.

Comment: Please post a link to the deleted posting you are referring to.

Comment: How ironic would it be to vote to delete this question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What can Y do about it?

Let's change the question to "What *should* Y do about it?"

Nothing, really, for the following reasons:

- It takes multiple users to close or delete a question. One person cannot do it (except in the case of moderators or gold tag badge users closing as a duplicate). Note also that after a period of time, close votes on unclosed questions expire and go away.
- Questions can similarly be reopened or undeleted by votes from multiple users. Therefore if a question *does* end up in a state that the community disagrees with, it will be corrected by the community.

So, there really isn't that much to worry about here. One user generally does not have the power to do what you say. Furthermore, if multiple users make incorrect decisions, a system is in place to allow the community to correct incorrect actions, so it all works out anyways.

Now, of course, if the question *should* have been closed and/or deleted, you could always attempt to improve it then ask for it to be reopened or start an open-minded and reasonable discussion on meta about it. If it then deserves to be reopened or undeleted, it will get what it deserves. If it doesn't deserve to be reopened or undeleted, then the best option is to accept that and move on.